# How to internationalize innerHtml using build-in angular i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

So I'm in a project to internationalize a web using build-in angular i18n.

But apparently in their code they use innerHtml to show a warning and I can't seem to find a way to internationalize this in the official documentation.

The html get the innerHtml using function:
`<p [innerHtml]="getMoveWarningMessage()"></p>`

while the ts looks like this:

```
return `
      By moving <strong>${this.movedSite.name || 'this site'}</strong> you will also be moving the
      ${sampleCount}
      ${activeJobCount}
      ${observationCount}
      linked to this site. Do you still want to move this site?
    `;
```

Is there any way to translate it using angular i18n?

Answer (score -1):

In their docs they said "For localization, you can use the Angular CLI to generate most of the boilerplate necessary to create files for translators, and to publish your app in multiple languages." or another way that I can recommend is to use ngx-translate for localization of your app.